# Using regular expression to separate sections

Tags: regex

Let's assume the following text

```
\n
Testing Section1\n
Testing Number1\n
\n
Testing Section2\n
Testing Number2\n
```

If I want to get separated section like:

```
Testing Section1\nTesting Number1\n
```

and

```
Testing Section2\nTesting Number2\n
```

What should I do?

Comment: you mean you want each match to be a separate section right? what context are you doing this in?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this?

```
(?:.+\n)+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW4yD9/5)

- `.+` Matches any char except newline character one or more times.
- `\n` Matches a  newline character.
- `(?:.+\n)+` `+` after the non-capturing group makes the whole non-capturing group to repeat one or more times.